# How would I add a fieldset to a resource in ActiveAdmin that does not correspond to a column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I would like to be able to add a field to a registered model in ActiveAdmin that does not correspond to a column on the model's table.

The model's table looks something like this:
| id | remote_id | created_at | updated_at |

And the code is as follows:

```
form do |form_obj|
  form_obj.inputs do
    form_obj.input :term, :required => true
  end
  form_obj.buttons
end
```

This issue I have is that the 'term' attribute does not exist on the model's table.  Instead it is set on a remote database that is accessed using the remote_id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a virtual attribute in the model that belongs to the form:

```
def term= (attributes)
  #this will be evaluated when you save the form
end

def term
  # the return of this method will be the default value of the field
end
```