# ActiveAdmin: form input without corresponding table attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

How can I set a textfield in an ActiveAdmin form, who do not correspond to a table attribute ?

I need it to build an autocomplete behavior, to populate a list of checkboxes.

Comment: You can use a form partial with custom inputs. Just make sure you add your attribute to permit_params in your active admin resource.

Comment: it works, thanks. If you copy paste it into the answer field, I will validate it.

Comment: nah, finally not. The partial don't work, it don't get the data for the edit :( still looking at it

Comment: you mean in the form itself? You can access the value with f.object.method_name, but it should work when you define an attr_accessible in the model class

Comment: and you're right again. Thx a lot, really, if you write anything in the answer field, I would be glad to give you points :)

Answer (score 3):

In case you want the value submitted back to your model, you can create a virtual attribute by adding `attr_accessible`, or explicitly define them in the model, as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25369957/426845):

```
def my_virtual_attr= (attributes)
  #this will be evaluated when you save the form
end

def my_virtual_attr
  # the return of this method will be the default value of the field
end
```

and you will need to add it to `permit_params` in the ActiveModel resource file.

In case you don't need the value submitted to the backend (needed for front-end processing for example), you can actually add any custom HTML to [ActiveAdmin form](https://activeadmin.info/5-forms.html), and this is an example code it:

```
ActiveAdmin.register MyModel do
  form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors # shows errors on :base
    f.inputs "My Custom HTML" do      
      f.li "<label class='label'>Label Name</label><a class='js-anchor' href='#{link}'>Link Text</a><span></span>".html_safe
      f.li "<label class='label'>Label 2 Name</label><input id='auto_complete_input'/>".html_safe
    end
    f.inputs "Default Form Attributes" do
      f.inputs          # builds an input field for every attribute
    end
    f.actions         # adds the 'Submit' and 'Cancel' buttons
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove model prefix from the params name

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register MyModel do
  form do |f|
    f.input :custom, input_html: { name: 'custom' } # instead of 'my_model[custom]'
  end
end
```

Comment: `undefined method 'custom' for ...`